# Solving logarithmic equation $2\log _{2}(x-6)-\log _{2}(x)=3$

Tags: logarithms

This is the question: $$2\log_{2} (x-6)-\log_{2} (x)=3$$

I think I would combine the two on the left to make $2\log_{2}\big({x-6\over x}\big) = 3$ but I'm stuck at what to do with the $2$ in front of the log. Would I divide it out to get $\log_{2}\big({x-6\over x}\big) = \tfrac{3}{2}$ or change to equation to exponential form?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this question for a while.

Comment: This is a bit hard to read.  Do you mean $2\log_2(x-6)-\log_2(x)=3$?

Comment: @lulu Yes, I mean that. Sorry, I'm not sure how to format it correctly

Comment: Then note that $n\log a= \log a^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't quite use your first step. First you should convert $2\log_{2}(x-6)$ to $\log_{2}(x-6)^2$, and then you can apply the subtraction of logs property to get $\log_{2}\frac{(x-6)^2}{x} = 3$. Then exponentiate to get rid of the logs and you should soon find yourself with a quadratic equation that you should be able to solve.

Comment: With this would I get x^(3 - 6^6)/x^3?

Comment: Raise $2$ to the power of each side. You should get $\frac{(x-6)^2}{x} = 8$.

Comment: So (x^2-36)/x=8 to x-36=8?

Comment: $(x-6)^2 = (x-6)(x-6) \not= x^2 - 36$

Comment: Thank you! So (x-6)(x-6) / x = (x^2 -12x+36) /x. But how would I divided 36 by x? I would multiply, right?

Comment: Correct. Then you will have $x^2 - 12x + 36 = 8x$.

Comment: So I would get (x-18)(x-2) to get x=18 and x=2 but then I would have to check to see if there are extraneous roots?

Comment: Cool. Thanks! The answer would just be x=18 because 2 wouldn't work because we can't log a negative number?

Comment: Correct, because if you plug $x=2$ back in, you have a term of $\log_{2}(-4)$ which is not possible

Comment: Thank you! Sorry that took so long.

Answer (score 2):

Use the rules $\log\big(\frac{a}{b}\big) = \log(a) - \log(b)$ and $\log(a^n) = n\log(a)$ to write everything as one logarithm. Then exponentiate.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can write $$\log_{2}{(x-6)^2}-\log_{2}{6}=3$$ and by the hint above
$$\log_{2}\frac{(x-6)^2}{x}=3$$

Answer (score 1):

With the basics rules:
$$ \log_a(b)=x \iff a^x=b \label{1}\tag{1}$$
$$ \log_a(b^n)=n\log_a(b) \label{2}\tag{2}$$
$$ \log_a(b) + \log_a(c)=\log_a(bc) \label{3}\tag{3}$$
You can solve this equation:
$$ 2\log_{2} (x-6) - \log_2(x)=3$$
from \eqref{2}:
$$ \log_{2} \big[(x-6)^2\big] - \log_2(x)=3$$
from \eqref{2}:
$$ \log_{2} \big[(x-6)^2\big] + \log_2\big(x^{-1}\big)=3$$
$$ \log_{2} \big[(x-6)^2\big] + \log_2\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)=3$$
from \eqref{3}:
$$ \log_{2} \Bigg[\frac{(x-6)^2}{x}\Bigg]=3$$
from \eqref{1}:
$$ 2^3 = \frac{(x-6)^2}{x} $$
$$ 8 = \frac{(x-6)^2}{x} $$
$$ 8x = (x-6)^2 $$
$$ 8x = x^2-12x+36 $$
$$ 0 = x^2-20x+36 $$
Here, $-20 = -18-2$ and $36=(-18)\cdot(-2)$, then:
$$ 0 = (x-18)(x-2) $$
Thus $x=18$ or $x=2$